# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API: return exception message when expecting custom model

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

In my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API application I have a method that returns a

```
Task<List<CustomModel> myFunctionHere
```

When I do a try/catch, how do I return the exception message, since the method is expecting this return type? (`Task<List<CustomModel>`)

I currently have the error message cannot implicitly convert type string to `Task<List<CustomModel>`

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solution for you:

1,You could jsut throw the exception and try with the build-in [exception handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-handler-1) instead of handling the error in catch block

Controller:

```
public async List<CustomModel> models SomeMethod(List<CustomModel> models)
    {
        if (......)
        {
            throw new Exception("exmessage");
        }
        return models;
        
    }
```

Call the middleware before other middleware:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerApp =>
{
    exceptionHandlerApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;

        
        context.Response.ContentType = Text.Plain;

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("An exception was thrown:");

        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
            context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error.Message);


      
    });
});
```

Result:

[image]

2,if you insist on handling the error in your controller, modify the return type of method to IActionResult

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeMethod(List<CustomModel> models)
    {
        try
        {               
            await .........;
            if (.....)
            {
                throw new Exception("Your exception");
            }
            return Ok(models);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(e);
        }
        
    }
```